# Saving selenium results/output at run time in text file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, save

I am running a script in **Python3** using **Selenium**. I am getting my output what I expected. Now, I want to save my output to a text, or `csv` or `json` file. When I am trying to run my script and save result to a file I am getting an Error with `open('bangkok_vendor.txt','a')` as `wt` :

> **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**

Which means loop in the program runs only one time and does not store data in file called `bangkok_vendor.txt`. In normal python scraper programs it would n't have any problem storing data but this is first time I am using `selenium`. Can you please help me with solution thanks.

I am trying to run this script from my terminal command and output is what to save to any file format :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import requests

contents =[]

filename = 'link_business_filter.csv'

def copy_json():
    with open("bangkok_vendor.text",'w') as wt:
        for x in script2:
            wt.writer(x)
            wt.close()

with open(filename,'rt') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links)

for link in contents:
    url_html = requests.get(link)
    print(link)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    open = browser.get(link)
    source = browser.page_source
    data = bs(source,"html.parser")
    body = data.find('body')
    script = body
    x_path = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div'
    script2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
    script3 = script2.text

    #script2.send_keys(keys.COMMAND + 't')
    browser.close()
    print(script3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to pass `script2` as a parameter for `copy_json` function and call it when you extract the data from the page.
- Change `w`rite mode to `a`ppend, otherwise the file will be reset every time you call `copy_json` function.
- Dont overwrite built-in functions like `open`, otherwise you won't be able to open a file to write data once you move onto the second iteration.

I refactored your code a bit:

```py
LINK_CSV = 'link_business_filter.csv'
SAVE_PATH = 'bangkok_vendor.txt'


def read_links():
    links = []
    with open(LINK_CSV) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            links.append(row[0])
    return links


def write_data(data):
    with open(SAVE_PATH, mode='a') as f:
        f.write(data + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

    links = read_links()
    for link in links:
        browser.get(link)

        # You may have to wait a bit here 
        # until the page is loaded completely

        html = browser.page_source

        # Not sure what you're trying to do with body 
        # soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        # body = soup.find('body')

        x_path = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div'
        main_div = browser.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
        text = main_div.text

        write_data(text)

    # close browser after every link is processed
    browser.quit()
```